# is `<element />` to `<element> </element>` valid?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it valid to replace elements with `<element />` to `<element></element>`. In this case i want to have,

`<input {attributes}></input>`

just so i can append validation data within... Also could this be possible from a `<br />` or `<hr />` etc?

Comment: Please! No `<br />`! [W3Fools](http://w3fools.com/#html_elements_br)

Comment: `<br />` was used as an example! obviously it wouldn't be needed on a break

Comment: Why don't you try the W3C Markup Validation service - http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<input>` tag does not have a `</input>` and there is no need for one.  Same for `<br>` and `<hr>`.  You can put validation data as attributes on the input tag (or any tag) with custom attributes like this:

```
<input type="text" data-validate="num">
```

If what you mean by validation is separate HTML that you want to display near the input tag, then put it in it's own tags before or after the `<input>` tag:

```
<input type="text"><span class="validHint">This field accepts only numbers</span>
```

Comment: NO! the validation is actually just a ui feedback, a div element as such with a icon of either tick or cross. Obviously </input> isn't normal which is why the question arisen, but this is XML which still would make it valid imo...

Comment: @Edhen - your question is apparently NOT very clear and it is not obvious what you are really trying to do.  If you want separate HTML before or after the `<input>` tag, then put it in it's own tags before or after the `<input>` tags.  If you want something else, then edit your question to be more specific about what you're really trying to accomplish.

Comment: this question was really curiosity. I know its easy to just place a js after or before an input element. but when i made a quick jquery function to append on an input element. I found it actually wrapped it properly as `<input>{js data}</input>`

Comment: @Edhen - There are a great many ways to create DOM trees which cannot be serialized to valid HTML. You have found one of them. DOM trees are not HTML and they are not XML either. There are DOMs that cannot even be serialized to well-formed XML. You will need to understand that each is a different representation of data, and make clear which of these you are asking about.

Answer (score 2):

`<input></input>` is not valid in neither HTML4.01 nor HTML5.

According to [W3C's validation service](http://validator.w3.org/): (reason highlighted)

> Validation Output: 1 Error
>
> Line 9, Column 15: **Stray end tag input.**
>      <input></input>

So here you go, you can not replace `<input>` with `<input></input>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to attach data to elements, why not use `data-*` attributes? (e.g. `<input data-color="red" />`) This is valid, and should be just as easy to implement.

Comment: i thought that was only html5, but anyways thats not really what i was after. the process i was trying to achieve was actually have a `<div class="error"></div>` which would display an error icon if the input's onchange returned false through an ajax validation check. why i wanted to see if i could do this, is simply so i could style the div relatively to the input element and grab it with ease from with jqeury when validating...

Comment: otherwise i would have to wrap the input and div icon inside another div as such.

Comment: Why not just wrap the input in a `div` then? I'm confused about the need to put data inside `input` elements.

Comment: because the div wouldnt had been needed till an onclick change event was excecuted. but now in doing so i would just have to dynamically put it in during the event. Also while i was experimenting as noted above, the jquery's append function actually wrapped it like i stated. this is the whole reason to my question, but never mind just a little extra code wont hurt to work around this. thanks

Comment: oh and to suppress your confusion, imagine a style.
`input {
   position: relative;
}
input div {
   position: absolute;
   right: -15px;
}`
that little bit off style would place it nicely to my current situation

Comment: I would just wrap the input in a `div`. If you happen to be using jQuery, this is [pretty straightforward](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).

Answer (score 0):

In classic HTML up to and including HTML 4.01, `<input></input>` is invalid. In practice, browsers ignore the stray end tag. They do not ignore the content between the tags, so `<input>foo</input>` achieves nothing as compared with `<input>foo`. HTML5 does not propose to change this.

In XHTML, `<input></input>` is valid but should not be used on the Web, according to XHTML specs. If you put any content between the tags, it becomes invalid, because the `input` element has been declared with EMPTY content model.

So you should take a completely different approach. It really depends on what you are trying to achieve, and should be discussed under some other heading. Depending on the problem, the solution could be one of the new HTML5 attributes, or a `data-` attribute, or a hidden field, or an element hidden some way, or maybe just data in the document tree.